# use None or EmptyMyObj in scala?

Tags: scala, nonetype

I understand the concept of `None`
I also understand how nice it is to have `MyObj` and also `MyEmptyObj`  but i cant figure out when its better to use `None` instead of `MyEmptyObj` and when I should be using `MyEmptyObj` instead of `None`.  Also I tend not to like to see methods that return `Option[MyObj]` it clutters my code I prefer to return `MyObj` and then seamlessly call its methods such as `MyObj.toJson` and thus `MyEmptyObj.toJson` will know to represent itself rather than having `case None: return some empty json` what do you think about this whole subject?
To the other side I can say that `None` goes very well with `flatMap` etc, so which to choose?

when to `None`

and when to `Empty`?

Comment: This is a very opinionated and subjective question but I generally go with the choice of `Option` when my object is not some container type and `MyObj` when it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` is great when you have no default value, but if you have a default, by all means use it.

As a very simple example, if you wanted to define a function called `amountOwed`, you could do this:

```
def amountOwed(bill: Int, alreadyPaid: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  val owed = bill - alreadyPaid.getOrElse(0)
  if(owed == 0) None // nothing to pay!
  else Some(owed)
}
```

But that's much more complex (and annoying) than it needs to be, since 0 makes perfect sense as both a "haven't paid anything" and "don't owe anything":

```
def amountOwed(bill: Int, alreadyPaid: Int): Int = {
  bill - alreadyPaid
}
```